# how to created array global? in nodejs

Tags: node.js

do i need to keep each link in a array within "request({..})", and then display it or work on the outside of "request({..})", this would be my code but does not work, any idea?

```
var request = require("request");
var cheerio = require("cheerio");
var arrayLinks = [];
request({
    uri: "http://www.some-url.com",
}, function(error, response, body) {
    var $ = cheerio.load(body);
    $("a").each(function() {
    var link = $(this);
    arrayLinks.push(link.attr("href"));
    });
});
arrayLinks.forEach(function(link){console.log(link)});
```

Answer (score 2):

For example:

```
var request = require("request");
var cheerio = require("cheerio");
var arrayLinks = [];
request({
    uri: "http://www.some-url.com",
}, function(error, response, body) {
    // Some logic.
    linkTheArray()
});

function linkTheArray() {
     arrayLinks.forEach(function(link){console.log(link)});
}
```

Now you can run it after the request is done. There is one other way, but it is pretty ugly. You can run a timeout function, until you get some data in the array

Comment: Now I understood it, thank you for your explanation was more clear with example.